# Sequelize query with limit, offset and order returns wrong number of records when order is descending

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a sequelize query to fetch paginated data. The limit is set to 12 for the query. But the query is returning fewer records even though there are a total of 15 records in the table. It seems like the more there are likes for a blog, the fewer records that are being returned. Can someone help me find the reason behind the problem? Here is the code for the query:

```
const { rows, count } = await Blog.findAndCountAll({
      subQuery: false,
      offset: 0,
      limit: 12,
      order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
      group: [
        "blog.id",
        "blog.title",
        "blog.content",
        "blog.coverImage",
        "blog.createdAt",
        "blog.updatedAt",
        "user.id",
        "user.name",
        "user.profileImage",
        "likes.userId",
        "likes.blogId",
      ],
      attributes: [
        "id",
        "title",
        "content",
        "coverImage",
        "createdAt",
        "updatedAt",
        [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("comments.id")), "commentCount"],
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          attributes: ["id", "name", "profileImage"],
        },
        {
          model: Like,
          attributes: ["userId"],
          required: false,
        },
        {
          model: Comment,
          attributes: [],
          required: false,
          where: { parentId: null },
        },
      ],
    });
```

This is the association between the models:

```
Like.belongsTo(Blog, { onDelete: "CASCADE" });
Blog.hasMany(Like, { onDelete: "CASCADE" });

Like.belongsTo(User, { onDelete: "CASCADE" });
User.hasMany(Like, { onDelete: "CASCADE" });
```

### Solution

It seems like I needed to remove `"likes.userId", "likes.blogId"` from the group and add `separate: true` in the include section of Like.
Here is the updated code:

```
const { rows, count } = await Blog.findAndCountAll({
      subQuery: false,
      offset: 0,
      limit: 12,
      order: [["createdAt", "DESC"]],
      group: [
        "blog.id",
        "blog.title",
        "blog.content",
        "blog.coverImage",
        "blog.createdAt",
        "blog.updatedAt",
        "user.id",
        "user.name",
        "user.profileImage"
      ],
      attributes: [
        "id",
        "title",
        "content",
        "coverImage",
        "createdAt",
        "updatedAt",
        [Sequelize.fn("COUNT", Sequelize.col("comments.id")), "commentCount"],
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          attributes: ["id", "name", "profileImage"],
        },
        {
          model: Like,
          attributes: ["userId"],
          required: false,
          separate: true
        },
        {
          model: Comment,
          attributes: [],
          required: false,
          where: { parentId: null },
        },
      ],
    });
```

From what I found out, it has something to do with how grouping works in SQL. I don't know the details though. I would really appreciate if someone could explain why the solution works.